# Did Meat Loaf ever perform the song live, or release a recording of "Everything works if you let it"?

Tags: history, recording, live-music, performance

The title of the song [Everything works if you let it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_Works_If_You_Let_It) was a saying of the character played by [Meat Loaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_Loaf) in his first starring role in the 1980 film [Roadie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadie_(1980_film)).

Did Meat Loaf ever perform this song live in a concert, or in a recording other than in the movie itself?

Comment: I need assistance with proper tagging; for example there isn't an `identify-this-performance` tag.

Comment: Different but complementary question asked in Movies SE: [Did Meat Loaf sing "Everything works if you let it" in the movie Roadie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/107041/45856)

Comment: Your tags are fine, though I'm not sure if history is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through [Meatloaf's set lists](https://www.setlist.fm/stats/meat-loaf-4bd6cb76.html#:%7E:text=Songs%20played%20total%20%20%20%20%20,%20%20736%20%2031%20more%20rows%20), and while it is not exhaustive, I can't locate any reference that he performed this song live. Also, I can't find any reference to Meatloaf performing this song on Youtube, something that you would expect to find for an artist of this fame.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this and post an answer!  :-)

Comment: I've never been able to get my hands on a copy of the movie, but after listening to Cheap Trick's [Everything Works If You Let It](https://youtu.be/dZN12kQHWCk) once again, I'm now sure that that is the version I'm remembering, and some how superimposing/lip-synching Meatloaf's face to it. I think some of my "lifestyle choices" in the 1980's has messed with my memories of the time :-)